# C++ Iterators that work for both std::vector and std::map

Tags: c++, iterator, containers

I need to implement something and it would be much easier if I could create, for example, an iterator that works both for `std::vector` and `std::map`. Is that possible? I'm talking about the iterators from the STL, not creating a new custom one.

I have a class which stores some elements in a `std::vector`. When I return those elements sometimes through different methods, I use `std::vector<...>::iterator`, and this iterator is later used by other parts of the program.

I want to create a new class which uses `std::map<...>` instead of `std::vector<...>`, so I can't return `std::vector<...>::iterator`, only `std::map<...>::iterator`. And no, I don't want to create an extra vector in this new class. The other parts of the program require an `std::vector<...>::iterator` instead of a `std::map<...>::iterator`.

Comment: This sounds like a possible XY problem. Can you give some more details about what you are actually trying to do and how you would use such a thing?

Comment: Or, a different question but which answer could help me, can you convert for example a `std::vector<...>::iterator` to `std::map<...>::iterator` and/or the other way around?

Comment: No. vector and map are different things. What is the problem you are actually trying to solve?

Comment: Basically I have a class which stores some elements in a `std::vector`. When I return those elements sometimes through different methods, I use `std::vector<...>::iterator`, and this iterator is later used by other parts of the program.

The thing is, I want to create a new class which uses `std::map<...>` instead of `std::vector<...>`, so I can't return `std::vector<...>::iterator`, only `std::map<...>::iterator`. And no, I don't want to create an extra vector in this new class.
The other parts of the program require an `std::vector<...>::iterator` instead of a `std::map<...>::iterator`

Comment: You have yet to explain your actual problem. You’ve basically repeated yourself, just in more detail.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a template function that accepts iterators of different types. As long as you use the given iterator as a bidirectional iterator, both vector and map iterators will work.

> Could you give me an example on how to do it

The standard library header `<algorithm>` is full of examples of function templates that accept iterators to different containers. Here is a simple example:

```
template<class InputIt, class T>
InputIt find(InputIt first, InputIt last, const T& value)
{
    for (; first != last; ++first) {
        if (*first == value) {
            return first;
        }
    }
    return last;
}
```

---

But if you are looking for a single iterator type, then there isn't such iterator in the standard library. It can be implemented though.

If the only thing that you do with the iterator is indirecting through it to access the object, then you can use a pointer instead of iterator of the container for that purpose in most cases. Only standard exception is `std::vector<bool>` which won't work with `bool*`.

Comment: "You can write a template function that accepts iterators of different types. As long as you use the given iterator as a bidirectional iterator, both vector and map iterators will work."
Could you give me an example on how to do it or some link where I can see this?

Comment: @vct12345 A `map::iterator` is a [bidirectional iterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/BidirectionalIterator). It can be incremented, decremented, and dereferenced. A `vector::iterator` is a [random access iterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/RandomAccessIterator), which is also a bidirectional iterator. As long as your logic is limited to things a bidirectional iterator can do, your logic will work equally for both `map` and `vector`